# How do I divide in the Linux console?

Tags: linux, math, command-line, divide

I have to variables and I want to find the value of one divided by the other. What commands should I use to do this?

Comment: Check this article: [http://www.basicallytech.com/blog/index.php?/archives/23-command-line-calculations-using-bc.html](http://www.basicallytech.com/blog/index.php?/archives/23-command-line-calculations-using-bc.html)

Comment: Is this really programming related? [http://stackoverflow.com/faq]

Comment: @frank-v Bash can be used for programming... also, that link to faq doesn't work

Answer (score 74):

In the bash shell, surround arithmetic expressions with `$(( ... ))`

```
$ echo $(( 7 / 3 ))
2
```

Although I think you are limited to integers.

Comment: Yes, bash is limited to integer math.

Answer (score 43):

```
echo 5/2 | bc -l
```

2.50000000000000000000

this '-l' option in 'bc' allows floating results

Comment: Cool; with `-l`, you get 20 decimal places by default *and* a math library is loaded that defines additional functions such as sine; to explicitly specify the number of decimal places, prepend the expression with `scale={numPlaces};` (too), as demonstrated in @user1504475's answer. In other words: `-l` is a convenient alternative to specifying `scale=20;`, but comes at a performance cost due to loading the library - the real-world impact appears to be negligible, though.

Answer (score 17):

Better way is to use "bc", an arbitrary precision calculator.

```
variable=$(echo "OPTIONS; OPERATIONS" | bc)
```

ex:

```
my_var=$(echo "scale=5; $temp_var/100 + $temp_var2" | bc)
```

where "scale=5" is accuracy.

```
man bc
```

comes with several usage examples.

Comment: Cool; one thing to note: not setting `scale` defaults to integer division - unless you specify `-l`, as @raytrace notes below, which apparently gives you 20 decimal places by default, but also loads a library with additional functions.

Answer (score 14):

You can use [awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) which is a utility/language designed for data extraction

e.g. for 1.2/3.4

```
>echo 1.2 3.4 | awk '{ print $2/$1 }'
0.352941
```

Answer (score 11):

I still prefer using *dc*, which is an RPN calculator, so quick session to divide 67 by 18 with 4 digits precision would look like

```
>dc
4k
67
18/p
3.7222
q
>
```

Obviously, much more available: *man dc*

Comment: A few pointers to possibly save some a trip to `man`: RPN = Reverse Polish Notation; in a nutshell: you enter the operands first, then the operator. A terminating `p` is needed to output the result. The non-interactive version of the above calculation is: `dc -e '4k 67 18 / p'`. Caveat: not setting the precision (with `{numPlaces}k`) defaults to 0, i.e., integer division.

Answer (score 10):

In bash, if you don't need decimals in your division, you can do:

```
>echo $((5+6))
11
>echo $((10/2))
5
>echo $((10/3))
3
```

Answer (score 5):

I assume that by *Linux console* you mean *Bash*.

If `X` and `Y` are your variables, `$(($X / $Y))` returns what you ask for.

Comment: You don't need the $'s for the variables

Answer (score 2):

Example of integer division using bash to divide $a by $b:

```
echo $((a/b))
```

Answer (score 2):

Something else you could do using raytrace's answer. You could use the stdout of another shell call using backticks to then do some calculations. For instance I wanted to know the file size of the top 100 lines from a couple of files. The original size from `wc -c` is in bytes, I want to know kilobytes. Here's what I did:

```
echo `cat * | head -n 100 | wc -c` / 1024 | bc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use:

```
echo "scale=4;$variablename/3"|bc
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use perl -e

```
perl -e 'print 67/8'
```

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same problem. It's easy to divide integer numbers but decimal numbers are not that easy.
if you have 2 numbers like 3.14 and 2.35 and divide the numbers then,
the code will be Division=`echo 3.14 / 2.35 | bc`
                       echo "$Division"
the quotes are different. Don't be confused, it's situated just under the esc button on your keyboard. 
THE ONLY DIFFERENCE IS THE | bc and also here echo works as an operator for the arithmetic calculations in stead of printing.
So, I had added  echo "$Division" for printing the value. Let me know if it works for you. Thank you.

Comment: The quotes are not showing here, So, just put the quotes(``) after = and after bc.

Comment: Those are not quotes. They are acute accents. They are not showing because StackOverflow uses them to highlight code snippets `some code here` was just wrapped in the acute accents.