# Counting executions of batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to count, in a file, the number of times a batch script has been executed.

In linux shell, this would be something like

```
counter=`cat buildnumber.txt`;
counter=`echo $counter+1|bc`
echo $counter > buildnumber.txt
```

but how does one do this in a batch file?

Comment: is using `bc` for such simple calculation a bit overkill?

Comment: Dunno whether there is a less overkill-y calculator available in bash...

Comment: yes, why not? [Math Commands](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/mathc.html) http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786/44425 http://stackoverflow.com/q/1088098/995714

Answer (score 3, accepted):

exactly the same logic, but using batch commands:

```
<buildnumber.txt set /p counter=
set /a counter +=1
echo %counter%>buildnumber.txt
```

Comment: Is it really `<buildnumber.txt` and then `set`? Looks a bit screwed up... Just curious.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 it doesn't matter *where*  you put the redirection. `set /p counter= <buildnumber.txt` works exactly the same. (run with `echo on` to see, that the parser interprets both possibilities the same way)

Answer (score 1):

This is my approch to count the number of execution for the batch script :

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Title Count the number of times my BATCH file is run
Mode Con Cols=60 lines=3 & color 0E
set /a count=1
set "FileCount=%tmp%\%~n0.txt"
If Not exist "%FileCount%" (
    echo !count! > "%FileCount%"
) else (
    For /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('Type "%FileCount%"') Do (
        set /a count=!count! + %%a
        echo !count! > "%FileCount%"
    )
)
echo.
echo        This batch script is running for "!count! time(s)"
EndLocal
pause>nul
```