# Arithmetic on "threads" wildcard in rule definition

Tags: python, multithreading, snakemake

In my workflow, I have two multithreaded programs that I am piping together. See the rule definition from my Snakemake file below.

```
rule do_the_thing:
    input: 'input.dat'
    output: 'output.dat'
    threads: 16
    shell: 'cmd1 --threads {threads} {input} | cmd2 --threads {threads} > {output}'
```

As written, the command will consume 32 threads. Is there a way I can perform arithmetic operations on the threads variable, so that (for instance) each command consumes only half of the available threads?

Comment: Perhaps, set `threads` to the total required, and [do the math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088098/how-do-i-divide-in-the-linux-console) in your shell command?

Comment: @JeeYem Yeah, although I'd need to use a ceiling function to make sure I don't assign 0 threads. Which is doable but messy. Might be cleaner to implement the rule using Python code and subprocess.

Comment: If you figure out a clean-ish approach, please post it.  It seems like there should be an easy way to do it on the python side, but I can't figure it out.  We're always piping through some file conversion, filter, or sort it seems...

Comment: @travc, maybe one of the options I suggest might help?

Answer (score 2):

There are quite some options:

- make use of [cpulimit](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/cpulimit):

```
shell: 
    cpulimit --include-children -l {threads}00 --\
    cmd1 --threads {threads} {input} | cmd2 --threads {threads} > {output}
```

- calculate the thread usage in the params:

```
threads: 16
params: lambda threads: max(1, threads//2)
shell: 
    cmd1 --threads {params.threads} {input} | cmd2 --threads {params.threads} > {output}
```

- Make use of snakemake [piped output](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#piped-output)

```
rule do_the_thing_first:
    output: pipe('output.pipe')
    threads: 8
    shell: 'cmd1 --threads {threads} {input} > {output}'

rule do_the_thing_second:
    input: 'output.pipe'
    output: 'output.dat'
    threads: 8
    shell: 'cmd2 --threads {threads} > {output}'
```